# Rendering Problems - Following Classes Not Found

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering, android-xml, android-appcompat

I recently updated Android Studio to version 1.2 and my AppCompat library to v22.0.0, SDK-Build-Tools version to 22.0.1. My target and compile sdk-version is 22 and my 'min-sdk-version' is 16.

The problem I am having is that in the xml-layout preview, I am getting an error namely: "Rendering Problems, the following classes cannot be found: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar". I did some surfing on the internet and tried the already provided solutions. They are as follows:

- Changing my (xml) preview to show android version target 21 or Android 5.0.1, 19, and 17
- Changing my styles theme to `Holo.NoActionBar` and other themes as well.
- Changing my minSdkVersion to 21 (above 20 basically)
- Restarted Android Studio... Twice
- Built the project about 5 times.

However, the problem still remains and I'm out of ideas. Could really use some help here. Thanks...

Also: The classes import just fine in my java file. It's just the preview.

EDIT: The preview works fine when I use android.widget.Toolbar. And my DrawerLayout doesn't work. I'm guessing there's something wrong with rendering the widgets from the support libraries?

Comment: Have you tried to change the *preview theme* (to Holo.dark for example) ?

Comment: @Rami yes I have. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wiped out my entire project and started all over again. That seemed to solve the problem. I'm guessing changing my configurations in between is what caused the mess. Thank goodness the project was just for recreation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and you may want to try to change the app theme in the style.xml to an appcompat app theme for example with mine I changed it to something like this.

```js
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

and then go to the Android Manifests file

```js
<application
        android:theme="@style/whatever_you_named_your_app_theme">
```

In the Android Manifests file you write whatever you wrote in the styles.xml under `<style name=""`
There is no need to lower your apps targetSDK.
Give me feedback if it worked for you

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I already have my theme set to appcompat in my styles.xml. It doesn't work. And the same configuration is also already present in my manifest.